# Access Shared Property of a generic list

Tags: .net

I have a list...

```vb
Public Class DatabaseCollection(Of T)
  Inherits List(Of T)

  Private Shared _LookupTables As Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
  Public Shared ReadOnly Property LookupTables As Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
    Get
      If _LookupTables Is Nothing Then
        _LookupTables = New Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
      End If
      Return _LookupTables
    End Get
  End Property  
End Class
```

and I want to access this property from elsewhere.

How do I do that?

Comment: Note that `Dictionary` is not thread safe. You might want to use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead if the property is access by multiple threads.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing or what you're asking. You seem to be extending the generic list with a property that seems to be independent of the list which strikes me as a bit off. Can you clarify exactly what the intent of this code is? Also I'm confused by "I want to access this property from elsewhere. How do I do that?". Your object feels a bit funky to me but is an object like any other and you access its properties like any other.

Comment: @Chris, you say "you can access it's properties like any other". Can you post an answer and show me some code that does that?  `DatabaseCollection.LookupTables` does not compile. `DatabaseCollection(Of ).LookupTables` does not compile either.

Comment: @toddmo: It looks like VB Shared does have slightly different semantics to c#'s static so I may be wrong. You should certainly be able to access "LookupTables" on an instance of that type at least...

Comment: Having had a further look `DatabaseCollection(Of string).LookupTables` works fine. Having then looked at your comment more closely you can't use open generic types (eg generic types without a type parameter) in this way (or in pretty much any way). If you have a generic type that you don't want to pass a type parameter to then you are almost guaranteed to be not using generic types correctly. Of note is that also using it on an instance works: `dim foo = new DatabaseCollection(Of string)` `foo.LookupTables.Dump()` (the Dump() method is from linqpad))

Comment: I'm inclined to go back to my original comment of asking what the code is meant to be doing? What problem are you trying to solve with this code because I'm not sure your approach is correct. That is the correct solution here is to work out where to put these lookuptables, not find a way to access them where they are. (though of course I don't know your exact case so migth be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new class, `Schema` which has a shared property containing a dictionary of meta information for each type, including the LookupTable. The `Schema` constructor takes the type in question so there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

The best way I can think to handle this would be another object that contains your DatabaseCollection class.  So your DatabaseCollection object would be a public property of your 'Container' Object.  Then you could have your LookupTables in the 'Container' object as well and it would relate 1-1 for each DatabaseCollection.

In addition to your DatabaseCollection class (if you have other properties/methods.  If you don't then it could just be a generic list.) and also include the following:

```
Public Class ContainerForDatabaseCollection
    Private Property _DbCollection as new DatabaseCollection
    Public Readonly Property DbCollection as DatabaseCollection(of String)
        Get
            return _DbCollection
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Shared Property _LookupTables As Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property LookupTables As Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
        Get
            If _LookupTables Is Nothing Then
                _LookupTables = New Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable)
            End If

            Return _LookupTables
        End Get
    End Property

public Sub New() 'Possibly include parameters for private properties...
    'Initialize Private properties
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can just do DatabaseCollection(Of String).LookupTables. But, each type of collection I can have for different types of T would have a seperate collection. Maybe there is no way to have one collection for all T. (I'm not the one who downvoted)

Comment: please add a code example to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thats pretty rough and it depends how much more you need to include, but the basic idea is have a container that holds both the databaseCollection object (list) and the LookupTables Dictionary.  Sorry if i'm still missing your goal!